# Cleaning tracked keyframes in After Effects

Tags: animation, tracking, adobe-after-effects

I'm new to After Effects and played with Mocha for After Effects a bit (which is very easy to pick up) and was wondering:

If I have a bunch of dense set of keyframes as a result of tracking, is there an After Effects option/script that can clean the data (reduce keyframes but maintain easing/timing)?

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually, Mocha - when imported to After Effects, has a key-frame for every frame.  If you click on the tracked layer and hit "U", you'll see this.

Usually, I wouldn't advise messing with the key-frames.

But, if you have to, try using the key-frame smoother.  It will take away key-frames and interpolate what's in-between the ones it does leave.

Another option it to manually delete key-frames you see as unnecessary.

Both options may have unexpected or unwanted results.

Comment: thanks for the hint(+1). Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with after effects but I have been looking at the javascript api and it might be possible to implement bezier curve fitting to estimate less key frames close to the original data set